# Java: How to make a JScrollPane around a BorderLayout

Tags: java, jscrollpane, border-layout

I am trying to make my first GUI-program and sofar everything went well, but now I have a problem:

First my Window had a minimum size and everything worek well, but now I dont want a minimum size, therefore I want a ScrollBar (vertical and horizonal) to be able to to see everything. I am trying to make this with a JScrollPane. The Problem is, that I have my program structured with a BorderLayout and I am not able to connect my JScrollPane with my BorderLayout. "JScrollPane Constructor is undefinied for BorderLayout". So I 
initialized a JPanel and set the layout to my BorderLayout.

```
windowContainer = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(10, 10));
```

Then I can connect the "windowContainer"(JPanel) with my JscrollPane

```
windowScrollPane = new JScrollPane(windowContainer);
```

After changing the rest of the code (changed "getContentPane.add..." to "windowContainer.add...") I didnt become errors but the JScrollPane didnt work. In my BorderLayout (LINE_START) is a JPanel with a minimim width of "300", so at least if the window is thinner than 300px the ScrollBar should appaer.
I spend a lot of research on the iinternet but everything what i found was "How to create a JScrollPane **in** a BorderLayout" and not "How to create a JScrollPane **around** the BorderLayout".

To clarify it i will uploat a picture (the red things are the JScrollBars).
Sorry I wasnt allowed to upload pictures, so please look here: http://www.fotos-hochladen.net/view/jscrollpanepu20315v9x.png

And i dont know how much code i have to give you, because everything would be to much, so just say something if you need more.

Here is again the important code about it:

```
... 
windowContainer = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(10, 10));
windowScrollPane = new JScrollPane(windowContainer);
frame.add(windowContainer);
...
```

PS: This is my first post, so please correct me if I did something wrong (about the post). And sorry for my english.

Comment: Did you try to add the jscrollpane to the panel then add the panel to the frame? You are addin the panel to the jscrollpane then adding the panel to the frame

Comment: Thanks for asking. What do you exactly mean?
windowContainer = new JPanel(windowScrollPane) doesnt work

Comment: I think you should be adding the jscrollpane to frame, not the jpanel

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry sometime I have a total black out.

 windowContainer = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(10,10));
 windowScrollPane = new JScrollPane(windowContainer);
 frame.add(windowScrollPane);

this works

Comment: I think so, im not at a computer to test it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. Method initComponent() use in contructor, or in place where you build view. Below I put example of JFrame with BorderLaylout as you want:

```
public class TestWindow extends JFrame{

int containerHeigh=300;
int containerWitdh=400;
private JPanel container;
private JPanel westPanel;
private JPanel eastPanel;
private JPanel northPanel;
private JPanel southPanel;
private JPanel centerPanel;
private JScrollPane scroll;

public TestWindow(){
    super("test");
    initComponents();
}

private void initComponents(){
    container=new JPanel();
    westPanel=new JPanel();
    eastPanel=new JPanel();
    northPanel=new JPanel();
    southPanel=new JPanel();
    centerPanel=new JPanel();

    //...fill panels of container
    westPanel.setBackground(new Color(95,183,70));
    eastPanel.setBackground(new Color(0,164,232));
    northPanel.setBackground(new Color(255,255,185));
    southPanel.setBackground(new Color(34,177,76));
    centerPanel.setBackground(new Color(152,114,203));

    scroll=new JScrollPane();
    scroll.setViewportView(container);

    BorderLayout containerLayout=new BorderLayout(containerHeigh, containerWitdh);
    container.setLayout(containerLayout);
    container.add(westPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    container.add(eastPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
    container.add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    container.add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    container.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    add(scroll);
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String...args){
    new TestWindow();
}
```

}

If you want you can use NetBeans for create Panels and other element of desctop applications. I generally build in NetBeans simple Panels, Dialog and then combine together dynamically in application. This provide me get user interface exactly what I want and prepare really fast.

Comment: Thanks a lot. JRowan already had the solution, but your look well too. "scroll=new JScrollPane();
    scroll.setViewportView(container);" is like "scroll=new JScrollPane(container)", right? 
And thanks for the tipp with NetBeans. The typical GUI doesnt look good everytime. 
PS: do I have to mark this question al solved?

Comment: your welcome.  About jScrollPane: is this same, but I prefer this solution, and I don't know why (maybe because NetBeans). You can mark this question as answered and you can mark JRoman answer as usefull for you